# Freemarker special symbol usage

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

What does below structure means in ftl? How do I create my own?
Where can I find more info about it?
Google doesn't seem to follow this.

@[someArray.someVariable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search by term XPath. @ in xpath mean "attribute". XPath is language of selecting nodes in XML.

```
<node attribute="value">
```

node[@attribute] = value in XPath.

Answer (score 0):

If it was indeed a FreeMarker expression, then it means nothing special, as `@` is a legal variable name. So it's just like `myHash[whatever]`, only the variable is called `@`, not `myHash`.